# PHP cURL - opt ifmodsice returns http code = 200

Tags: php, http, curl

I'm trying to set up a curl request for getting remote files only if they are been modified since my stored timestamp.

I want to manage the http code of my cURL request, here is an example.

I have stored a timestamp of the last download of file XX. `2014-12-08 06:56:03`.
My cURL request

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE, strtotime($timestamp));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMECONDITION, CURL_TIMECOND_IFMODSINCE);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

As the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) says

> CURLOPT_TIMECONDITION
>
> How CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE is treated. Use CURL_TIMECOND_IFMODSINCE to return the page only if it has been modified since the time specified in CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE. If it hasn't been modified, a "304 Not Modified" header will be returned assuming CURLOPT_HEADER is TRUE. Use CURL_TIMECOND_IFUNMODSINCE for the reverse effect. CURL_TIMECOND_IFMODSINCE is the default.

So, if my timestamp is `2014-12-08 06:56:03` and the filetime of the remote file is `2014-12-08 04:59:03` it has to return an http code of 304, but I'm getting always an http code of 200.
Have I misunderstood the docs?

These are the timestamps in seconds

- local file `1418021941`
- remote file `1418014742`

and this are the info of the above curl request

```
array(26) {
  ["url"]=> string(32) "XXX"
  ["content_type"]=> string(24) "application/octet-stream"
  ["http_code"]=> int(200)
  ["header_size"]=> int(251)
  ["request_size"]=> int(113)
  ["filetime"]=> int(1418014742)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=> int(0)
  ["total_time"]=> float(0.100412)
  ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.010285)
  ["connect_time"]=> float(0.05576)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.055878)
  ["size_upload"]=> float(0)
  ["size_download"]=> float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=> float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=> float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=> float(371712)
  ["upload_content_length"]=> float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.100382)
  ["redirect_time"]=> float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=> string(11) "XXX"
  ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { }
  ["primary_port"]=> int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=> string(11) "XXX"
  ["local_port"]=> int(XX)
}
```

These are the info if I change the timestamp of my local file to be less than the remote one `2014-12-06 06:56:03`

```
array(26) {
  ["url"]=> string(32) "XXX"
  ["content_type"]=> string(24) "application/octet-stream"
  ["http_code"]=> int(200)
  ["header_size"]=> int(251)
  ["request_size"]=> int(113)
  ["filetime"]=> int(1418014742)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=> int(0)
  ["total_time"]=> float(0.583712)
  ["namelookup_time"]=> float(0.011975)
  ["connect_time"]=> float(0.056813)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=> float(0.056977)
  ["size_upload"]=> float(0)
  ["size_download"]=> float(371712)
  ["speed_download"]=> float(636807)
  ["speed_upload"]=> float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=> float(371712)
  ["upload_content_length"]=> float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=> float(0.103772)
  ["redirect_time"]=> float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=> string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=> string(11) "XXX"
  ["certinfo"]=> array(0) { }
  ["primary_port"]=> int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=> string(11) "XX"
  ["local_port"]=> int(XX)
}
```

As you can see there is a difference between the two, the `[size download]`, =0 in the first one, >0 in the second one.

Any suggestion? I will always get an http code = 200?

--------- edit

This is the header I get back with local timestamp `2014-12-08 06:59:01`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: nginx Date: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 10:23:06 GMT Content-Type: application/octet-stream Content-Length: 371712 Last-Modified: Mon, 08 Dec 2014 04:59:02 GMT Connection: keep-alive ETag: "54853016-5ac00" Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you misunderstood the dosc.

If it hasn't been modified, a "304 Not Modified" header will be returned assuming CURLOPT_HEADER is TRUE.

No change -> Return a "304 Not Modified" header.

Modified -> Return 200

－－－－－－－－－round 2－－－－－－－－－

File's Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 05:37:48 GMT.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT");
$url = "...";
$timestamp = "2014-12-18 05:37:48";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE, strtotime($timestamp));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMECONDITION, CURL_TIMECOND_IFMODSINCE);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
```

1, if i use above test code, it will return a head like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 08:27:55 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
ETag: "17c-50a76fe108d7a"
```

2, when i change the $timestamp, it will return this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 08:31:02 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 05:37:48 GMT
ETag: "17c-50a76fe108d7a"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 380
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html
```

I think you should set the timezone, if i don't set the timezone it always return 200.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's odd because with the CURLOPT_TIMECONDITION get the body only if the resource hasn't been modified since the timestamp in CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE, but the http code will always be 200 - also if the resource has not been modified since my timestamp? In what case I will get a 304? If I query a file that has been modified one year ago `2013-12-22 04:59:00` I still get 200.

Comment: I found the problem. you should set the timezone. -- date_default_timezone_set("Etc/GMT");